# ASP.Net MVC5: Extra segment in routing causes issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

to handle my routing issue i add extra segment in routing which not redirecting me to edit action.

### see my routing which causing problem

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "Customers/Action/Edit/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);

OR

routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "Customers/Edit/Action/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);
```

**i test above 2 different set of routing for PageWithId but none work**

### see RouteLink code

```
@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "PageWithId",
new
{
        controller = "Customers",
        action = "Edit",
        id = item.CustomerID,
        page = ViewBag.CurrentPage
})
```

### my edit action code

```
public ActionResult Edit(int page, string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    if (customer == null)
    {
    return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
    return View(customer);
}
```

now tell why this url `http://localhost:2020/Customers/Action/Edit/1/AlFAKI` not redirecting me to edit action?

### see my full routing code

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "PageWithSort",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{SortColumn}/{CurrentSort}",
                defaults: new { action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional, SortColumn = UrlParameter.Optional, CurrentSort = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "Customers/Action/Edit/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);

OR

routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "Customers/Edit/Action/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: Perhaps it is the order of your maproutes.  It may be getting routed by the wrong one.  Try moving your maproutes to the top and see if your parameters get mapped correctly.

Comment: `Customers/Action/Edit/1/AlFAKI` has 5 segments - it matches your first route - The order of your routes matters (and as a side note, only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`)

Answer (score 0):

Your route looks wrong, I believe you are trying to do is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageWithId",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Customers", action = "Edit" }
);
```

And your url will be: http://localhost:2020/Customers/Edit/1/AlFAKI

Comment: i use this first `url: "{controller}/{action}/{page}/{id}",` then goes to edit action but id was getting null always. see my full routing code.

Comment: I`ve just tested it here and I got the 2 parameters without problem. How was your url ? Did you remove the word "Action" from the url ?

Comment: yes i remove action. my url looks http://localhost:2020/Customers/Edit/1/AlFAKI but AlFAKI was not passing as id...it was always null. when url becomes http://localhost:2020/Customers/Edit/1?id=AlFAKI then it was working

Comment: Another point: Is "ViewBag.CurrentPage" an integer value ? In your controller page is int and id is string. Is that correct ?

Comment: ViewBag.CurrentPage" is an integer.